# Access is replacing # with . when exporting to a csv

Tags: vba, csv, ms-access

I have a small access program that is exporting data to a csv. The csv needs to have field headers that include #'s.  However when I export using VBA:

```
DoCmd.TransferText acExportDelim, "ThisExport", "GeneralQuery", "C:\ThisFile\data.csv", True
```

It changes the #'s into .'s:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Use valid identifiers like `Email_1`.

Comment: I wish it were that easy.  The data I'm exporting has to have those exact headers so that it can be imported into another software looking for those headers.

Comment: Perhaps have to use textfile read/write. Export the file with TransferText then use Read/Write to modify. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57194061/microsoft-access-vba-edit-text-file

Comment: Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18232469/how-can-i-edit-a-line-in-a-file-opened-with-filesystemobject-in-vba

Comment: Normalize your database. You should never have repeated fields like that. You need a separate table that is related many to one with just emails and IDs. Then you can have an arbitrary number of emails.

Answer (score 1):

One approach uses a UNION query:

```
SELECT 0 AS Cat, "Email #1" AS A, "Email #2" AS B, "Email #3" AS C FROM Table1
UNION SELECT 1, [Email #1], [Email #2], [Email #3] FROM Table1;
```

Set TransferText HasFieldNames argument to False and export query.

However, if your import app cannot deal with presence of Cat field, use textfile read/write methods. This is a fairly common topic. Export data with TransferText then use read/write methods to modify.